# RFID/Barcode reader sending code to web application

Tags: html, laravel, barcode, barcode-scanner, rfid

So I've been developing a Web Application with Framework Laravel (which I'm new to), more likely will become a dashboard and I'm currently stuck with this problem, didn't find anything related to this and now it's getting a little frustrating.

I've bought a RFID/Barcode bluetooth scanner and need to collect both RFID and barcode in my application so later on I can work with my database, the thing that is currently annoying me is connecting my scanner to Laravel front-end which I particularly have never done before.

Any ideas I should approach/consider?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would probably be a decent amount of work, but the Bluetooth web API might be your only shot if I understand correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Phix , I've read about this API and it seems promising, hopefully it isn't that hard to understand and start using since it might be my only resource to be able to solve this.

Comment: I've seen some talks about people using the API to control other Bluetooth devices like drones etc, but it's fairly involved. Good luck, and write a blog post about it when you succeed!

Comment: I've been considering doing this with python as well since it seems to be more robust than general PHP/Laravel, but firstly I'll try using this API and see how it goes. For sure I'll keep this updated as I achieve something worth sharing.